# Cookie value reverts back to previous value after changing

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, plugins

I have this custom pligin that im using in order to save the user's language preferences. I store it as a cookie like so:

```
<?php
    
    add_filter( 'init', 'aws_set_language_cookie', 999 );
    function aws_set_language_cookie() {
        global $TRP_LANGUAGE;
        if ( isset( $TRP_LANGUAGE ) ) {
            $result = setcookie( 'language', $TRP_LANGUAGE, time() + ( 30 * DAY_IN_SECONDS ), "/", "" , true, true );
        }
    }
    
    ?>
```

Now if you take a look at the website https://ugrandchurch.com/ open cookies in inspect element after switching to Spanish.
You will see that a cookie by the name of "language" created which holds the value of "es_ES" is saved but it changes to "en_EN" after 3 seconds.

How can I make sure that the value of Spanish "es_ES" is kept instead of being taken overriten by "en_EN".

The WordPress language plugin used here is by the name of TranslatePress

Comment: Is the site using Automatic User Language Translation maybe? https://translatepress.com/automatic-user-language-detection-in-translatepress/

Comment: @admcfajn No its not using that its a pro addon